# Using Django and Ajax to dynamically update information not working

Tags: python, django

When I have a many-to-many field that I want to change dynamically (ie, from the view to update the database without refreshing the entire page), such as when a user clicks a 'Follow' button for an object (as many different users can follow many different objects) then Ajax will make the request and the database will be updated. 
However, this Ajax call does not seem to work for dynamically changing a boolean property (changing something to True or False) for any given object.

This class-based view works to dynamically add or remove a user:

```
if user.userprofile in obj.followers.all():
    following = False
    obj.followers.remove(user.userprofile)
else:
    following = True
    obj.followers.add(user.userprofile)
updated = True
```

However, this code does not work to change an attribute to True or False:

```
if user.is_authenticated():
    if user.userprofile.content_pref == True:
        display = False
        user.userprofile.content_pref = False
    else:
        display = True
        user.userprofile.content_pref = True
updated = True
```

How might I achieve this effect? Through clicking on a button, I want a user to toggle their model object attribute from False to True or vice-versa...Thanks

Comment: Maybe `user.save()`?

Comment: @Blurp user.save() looks like it's working - this seemed odd because for the M2M field I didn't have to call the save method, any idea why?:)

Comment: [The docs for related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) state that `add` does a bulk update by default, probably for performance reasons.

Comment: BTW, don't load all the 'followers' with it's attributes just to check if something exists! Maybe use this `if obj.followers.filter( id = user.userprofile_id ).exists():` instead.

Comment: Hi jayt, please show us your AJAX, and tell me if you see the URL visited -in the console- when you click the button